# How do I zoom picture in an ASP.NET web forms imagebutton?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I have an asp. Net web forms application which allow a user to display a picture in an imagebutton. My dilemma is that the pictures my users have are enormous (7200 pixels by 4800 pixels). I want to be able to zoom in to the picture while keeping the imagebutton the same size.
What is the easiest way to do this?

Additionally the image is displayed after its URL is found by an Upload File control

Here is my .aspx code:

```
<div class="picontainer" style="width: 900px" >
                <asp:ImageButton ID="pic" runat="server" OnClick="Image_Click" />

        </div>
```

.css for div picontainer:

```
.picontainer {
        max-height: 600px;
        max-width: 900px;
        overflow: scroll;
}
```

This is how I choose ImageButton.ImageUrl:

```
string folderPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/");
if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
}
string filename = FileUploader.FileName;
FileUploader.SaveAs(folderPath + filename);
string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
if (ext ==".png" || ext==".jpg" || ext==".gif" || ext==".jpeg")
    pic.ImageUrl = "~/Files/" + Path.GetFileName(FileUploader.FileName);
```

What I have tried:

I have tried importing methods from the Windows Forms library.

I also tried saving the picture as a Bitmap and trying to resize the picture by multiplying the bitmap's size by a zoom factor and outputting a new Bitmap. I'm not sure how to set the new URL when using this method

Comment: not so simple - look a full example here -> https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6620/ASP-NET-Image-Manipulation-Examples-Adding-Zooming

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand what your application is trying to do. But if you want to resize images on the fly, I would take a look at the .NET [ImageResizer](https://imageresizing.net/) library.

You can also pull it into your project using [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ImageResizer/).

Also, you shouldn't need duplicate CSS in your markup.

Comment: I want the user to be able to zoom out of the imagebutton with the push of a button.

Comment: Same button? Other button? As I said, I just don't get what you're trying to achieve visually. Maybe a screenshot? Remember, with a push of a button you can call into this library and resize something on the fly.

Comment: it is probably best implemented client side with a javascript image zooming library. Do a google search and you will see tons of different examples.

Comment: Just curious, why would it be "best" to do this on the client side? Would not 7200 X 4800 images seriously add to the payload?